# Is it possible to purchase the OEM USB sync cable?

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to buy the genuine Apple USB sync cable for iPad/iPhone/iPod? I know there are many aftermarket cables available, but most of them seem inferior.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inferior." I have both apple brand cables and cheap Chinese knock offs and the only important difference I've noticed is that the knockoffs don't fit into my iPhone 4 or 4S with the apple bumper on. Other than that they work fine with my iPad 2 and my wife's iPad 1.

Comment: Good point, "inferior" is too broad. The trouble I have that the cable I have that doesn't fit my wife's iPad with the case on.

Comment: Right, but sans case it will work fine. So, some of the third party cables have a thicker plastic housing on the iDevice end which, depending on bumper/case make the cable too big / fat to fit. Some of Apple's earlier iPod cables, which fit the port are too fat as well when an iPhone has a bumper on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](http://store.apple.com/xc/product/MA591G/B) - look for Apple USB to dock connector in the store.

It also comes with most chargers and dock accessories if you want a bundle.

Comment: to add to this, some of the third party cables do not support the power necessary to connect some of Apples devices.